# Getting gallery instead of single attachment

Tags: gallery

I'm working on a template right now. At the moment I'm trying to work with a regular gallery as given by Wordpress. But instead of getting only an attachment by clicking on an image, I want to get the entire gallery of the post.
I tried to use `get_post_gallery()` for this but can't get it to work in any way. Is there a way to achieve this or maybe even a Plugin that does something alike? I'd be really thankful if anyone could help.

Comment: If you can share your code here then I can help you.

Comment: What do you mean "get the entire gallery" when clicking? What does that mean?